# identifying between an open curve and a closed ring using shapely

Tags: python, geometry, shapely

Shaeply has the `object.ring`, but the object itself is already pre-determined by
LineString or LineRing.
An example is

```
>>> LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, -1)]).is_ring
False
```

How should one determine if the object is a open curve, or a ring.
For example, the object below should be considered as an open curve.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your data is using LineStrings to capture things that are actually LinearRings, then you can check its ring-ness by simply checking if the first and last point are the same.

```
first, last = yourLineString.boundary
if first == last:
   print("It's a ring!")
```